# (Highcharts) Prevent overlapping of series in stacked step area chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, stacked-area-chart

This is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/994pvk8o/

When I add negative values to the chart, at X point 194, P1 and P3 = 1, but P2=-1. The total sum of the values is 1, and is actually hiding P1 and P2. (Click on P2 to disable it).

So, I want the negative values to be separately stacked from the positive values. We won't get overlapping areas then.

Is there an option that I can use with highcharts to do this? I tried:

```
plotOptions:{
    series:{
        threshold: -1
    }
}
```

but, no luck.

Comment: This issue is discussed here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5671
As was mentioned in the github, you need to set a different stack for negative values and linked those 2 series together. http://jsfiddle.net/994pvk8o/2/

Comment: Thanks, that worked!